# ArcMap redraws every layer when changing just one

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have 10 layers or so loaded in a data frame in ArcMap 10.2. Some are complex such as NHD hydrology and Tiger roads.

Why does ArcMap redraw all layers when I change the symbology of just one? Is there a way to stop ArcMap from doing this behavior?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [basemap layers](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/02/02/basemap-layers-new-at-arcgis-10/) to solve this. Once you are happy with the symbology of your layers you can right click the data frame and select New Basemap Layer (see below) which is similar to a group layer.

You can then drop the layers into this group, it will redraw them once and then 'store' this view rather than redrawing every time you make a change. If you need to make any changes to layer you can pull it out of the basemap group edit it and drop it back in.

This will make it much quicker to navigate round your map.

[image: Basemap Layer]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great! Why do some layers I add to my Basemap Layer show warnings (small triangle icon with ! sign)? Is this a projection issue?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know it is just a projection thing. (have you checked the project and layers have the same projection?). But to be honest, I normally ignore the warning triangle as it still displays the data without any issues.

Comment: Great.. This works better but it seems weird that I have to drag a layer out to change its symbology and then drag it back in. What might the logic be behind this?

Comment: My understanding is that the basemap takes a 'snapshot' of the data effectively storing it in memory rather than redrawing and to do that the layer has to be fixed which is why you have to take it out of the basemap layer to change it.

Comment: If you right click the basemap layer in the table of contents, then select "Analyze Basemap Layer..." a panel will appear explaining how to fix the warnings/errors.

Comment: From: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000006n000000   "Because basemap layers are cached, there are limitations on what you can do with them. For example, you cannot edit the layers in a basemap or change the layer symbology. If you need to make edits or layer updates, drag the layer out of your basemap, make the changes, and drag the updated layer back into the basemap layer."

Comment: Is anyone noticing an improvement in drawing speed when using basemaps? I have 100 or so layers in my map, some complex and i don't see much improvement by moving them into basemap layers - Arc map refreshes differently but I wouldn't say it's faster. Map still refreshes every time the extent changes.

Comment: If you are in the data view and making minor movements, then yes it will probably refresh the layers in the basemap every time. The real benefit of this is if you're changing the symbology of some of the layers / adding more data in (which was the original question) or for things like data driven pages where the basemap group will store the view even when you switch back and forth between pages as they effectively have a fixed extent.